# Easily available alternative to anti static bags

Tags: antistatic, static-electricity

I want to pack some electronic components, but I don't have an anti static bag. Are there any easily available materials that can be used instead.
Any frugal tricks ??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aluminium foil? Just if you don't have any power supplies inside...

Comment: Wrap 'em in tinfoil. And you see ICs pushed into tinfoil wrapped twice around polystyrene when things got desperate - stayed away from that one as polystyrene produces static and if the tinfoil tears away...

Comment: @TonyM yup seen that too... cringed every time. Don't let the legs poke through the tinfoil though.

Comment: It's pretty easy to make an "envelope" out of two layers of aluminum foil with a sheet of paper in between to give it some extra strength if need be so the legs don't poke through.